# datatable Error : Request for unknown parameter datatable version 1.10.12

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

**JS:**

```
[  
   {  
      "id":6,
      "firstName":"Paul",
      "lastName":"Allen",
      "address":"25 1845 Owagner Lane Seattle Washington 98133",
      "shift":"Afternoon",
      "salary":350000,
      "imageUrl":"paul_allen.jpg"
   },
   {  
      "id":7,
      "firstName":"Mark",
      "lastName":"Doethy",
      "address":"DATA: SELECT ALL\r\n8267 Cozy Stead, Yellepit, Nunavut, X6D-9S8, CA,",
      "shift":"Afternoon",
      "salary":2000000,
      "imageUrl":"mark_young.jpg"
   },
   {  
      "id":9,
      "firstName":"Mary Alice ",
      "lastName":"Young",
      "address":"Wisteria Lane",
      "shift":"Morning",
      "salary":4500000,
      "imageUrl":"MaryAlice5.jpg"
   }
]

$('#drivers').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: '/api/drivers/getlist/',
    dataSrc: ""
  },
  paging: false,
  colums: [
    {
      data: 'id'
    }
  ]
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table-condensed" id="drivers">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Driver Id</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please MOD, Tag the question as javascript , JQuery remove Tag c# , modify title  by including Datatable Plugin for jquery

Comment: Hi.. please correct the column spelling first, it should be `columns` to `colums` and check again.

Comment: Take a look on [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `colums` is certainly a parameter with which DataTables would be unfamiliar.